# InsufficientAuthenticationException when using OAuth2RestTemplate from RestController

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am building a Spring Boot application which calls a 3rd party REST API (Infor ION API) secured by OAuth2.

I have built my OAuth2RestTemplate like this:

```
@Service
public class GenericIONAPIServiceImpl implements GenericIONAPIService {

  @Override
  public IONHubspotAPIResponse getFromHubspotAPI(String endpoint, Map<String, String> queryParams,
      IONConfiguration ionConfiguration) {
    String url = ionConfiguration.getBaseUrl() + "/" + ionConfiguration.getTenentId() + endpoint;
    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplate(ionConfiguration);
    ResponseEntity<IONHubspotAPIResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, IONHubspotAPIResponse.class);
    if (response != null) {
      return response.getBody();
    }
    return null;
  }

  private OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource(IONConfiguration ionConfiguration) {
    ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();

    // List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>(2);
    // scopes.add("read");
    resource.setAccessTokenUri(ionConfiguration.getBaseAuthUrl() + ionConfiguration.getTokenEndpoint());
    resource.setClientId(ionConfiguration.getClientId());
    resource.setClientSecret(ionConfiguration.getClientSecret());
    resource.setGrantType("password");
    // resource.setScope(scopes);

    resource.setUsername(ionConfiguration.getUsername());
    resource.setPassword(ionConfiguration.getPassword());

    resource.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);

    return resource;
  }

  private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate(IONConfiguration ionConfiguration) {
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(ionConfiguration));
  }
}
```

In the above snippet, I am using `getFromHubspotAPI()` inside my `@RestController` like so

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

  @Autowired
  private GenericIONAPIService ionAPIService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/hubspot-webhooks/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public IONHubspotAPIResponse getCompany() {
    IONHubspotAPIResponse response = ionAPIService.getFromHubspotAPI("/CustomerApi/HubSpot/companies/v2/companies/2789731554", null, ionConfiguration);
    return response;
  }
}
```

I have setup access to the `/hubspot-webhooks/test` API to `permitAll()` in my ResourceServerConfiguration like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource-id";

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/userAccounts").permitAll()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/hubspot-webhooks/**").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
  }

}
```

When the `ionAPIService.getFromHubspotAPI(...)` method is invoked from the `RestController` I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:91) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:738) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:586) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at com.leanswift.hubspotm3connector.service.ionapi.impl.GenericIONAPIServiceImpl.getFromHubspotAPI(GenericIONAPIServiceImpl.java:39) ~[main/:na]
        at com.leanswift.hubspotm3connector.service.ionapi.impl.IONHubSpotServiceImpl.getCompanyDetails(IONHubSpotServiceImpl.java:21) ~[main/:na]
        at com.leanswift.hubspotm3connector.rest.controller.HubSpotWebhooksController.createCompany(HubSpotWebhooksController.java:132) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at com.leanswift.hubspotm3connector.rest.filter.HubSpotAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(HubSpotAuthenticationFilter.java:43) ~[main/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:643) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I have called the same method from inside a `@SpringBootTest` class which will actually return a response object without any exceptions.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class TestGenericIONAPIService {

  @Autowired
  private GenericIONAPIService ionAPIService;

  @Test
  public void testHubSpotCompanyAPI() {
    IONHubspotAPIResponse response = ionAPIService.getFromHubspotAPI("/CustomerApi/HubSpot/companies/v2/companies/2789731554", null, ionConfiguration);
    assertNotNull(response);
  }
}
```

I have made sure the `ionConfiguration` object in both cases are the same by copy pasting the same initialisation code for both.

Why is this happening (same method throwing an exception when called from RestController but works when called from SpringBootTest)?

**Major Edit 1:**
After a lot of debugging I found that

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

is returning `null` from inside

```
AuthenticationTokenProviderChain#obtainAccessToken(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, AccessTokenRequest request)
```

method when executing from `@SpringBootTest` whereas it is returning an object with some data when executing from `@RestController`.

So now the question is, is the `OAuth2RestTemplate` I created dependent on the authentication I set up for my application? If yes, how can I make the `OAuth2RestTemplate` independent of my application's security config, because it doesn't make sense for me to apply the same security policies while calling a third party API.

**Major edit 2:**
My dependencies from `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.8.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:1.1.0.RELEASE'

    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'

    implementation 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

Comment: Do you have 'spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar' available in your project? Check you dependancies in pom.xml.

Comment: Yes I do. The project wouldn't compile if the dependecy was missing right?
`implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.8.RELEASE'`

Comment: What are the relevant dependencies versions?

Comment: @Boris updated in question

Comment: So you wwant to access "hubspot-webhooks/test" without any security ?

Comment: Why don't you use [spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#authorization-server) module? Also why do you use old `commons-dbcp` and not the `commons-dbcp2` which is managed by Spring Boot?

Comment: @MyTwoCents yes, hubspot-webhooks/test should be accessile without any security, but it needs to call a 3rd party API secured by OAuth2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

Just override the following method inside your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/hubspot-webhooks/**");
  }
}
```

**Long Answer**

Like I mentioned in the updates to the question. When I run the `restTempalte.exchange()` call from the `@SpringBootTest` class, the `Authentication` object returned inside the `AccessTokenProviderChain` is `null` whreas from the `@RestController`, it is the `Authentication` object for your `@RestController` method. And when I make the request to my `@RestController` if I dont provide any authentication (which is my case), the following implementation inside `AccessTokenProviderChain` throws the exception:

```
if (auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
  if (!resource.isClientOnly()) {
    throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
        "Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)");
  }
}
```

So when I add the `ignoring()` in the `WebSecurity` object like shown above, the `Authentication` object returns `null` just like when I ran it from the `@SpringBootTest`.

Now, this will actually solve the issue, but I am still surprised why the `OAuth2RestTemplate` is using the authentication configured on the application when the purpose of `OAuth2RestTemplate` is to call a completely different API.

May be someone could clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

In your configure add `"/hubspot-webhooks/test"` URL to permit which will be skipped from Security Filter.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/hubspot-webhooks/test").permitAll()
            ...
}
```

3rd Party API logic is written as a Service that is independent of Spring Security.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the question. The execption is not thrown becuase of the HttpSecurity of my application. It is thrown when the third party API is called using the RestTemplate. And yes, the /hubspot-webhooks/test API is already accessible without authentication

Comment: Problem seems to be when I initialize `new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(ionConfiguration))`, it seems to be referring to `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` which seems to return the `Authentication` object for `/hubspot-webhooks` API.

Comment: So when `/hubspot-webhooks` API does not have any client authentication set, the third party API call (using the `OAuth2RestTemplate` fails because it is actually expecting client authentication to be present

Comment: I have clarified this in the question now